# Android Layout: 3 buttons at the bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am designing a layout which has 3 buttons at the bottom very adjacent to each other. Because I want to add some more button in the middle of the screen too so what I am doing is I set up a whole screen as a Relative Layout and to get the 3 buttons at the bottom I add a Linear Layout to contain those 3 buttons. However, it gets stuck. The button does not show 3 buttons in the bottom. Here is my xml layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:weightSum="1">

           <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />
          <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" 
         android:layout_weight="0.3"/>
                              <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
         android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is coming from your `android:layout_width="0dp"` on the three buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="1">
```

android:orientation="vertical" change this to horizontal
android:layout_width="wrap_content" change this to fill_parent

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" />
```

android:layout_alignParentLeft="true", and i dont think this does work in a linearlayout .